# Which MTA to install on a Ubuntu hardy EC2 Instance

Tags: ubuntu

Which MTA should I install on a Ubuntu hardy EC2 Instance? I hear that Postfix is the default MTA on Ubuntu.

I will also need installation and config instructions. This MTA will deliver mail to a SMTP server running outside of the AWS environment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Postfix is indeed a very versatile and well documented MTA.  Another one I played around with is Exim4, although this was on Debian5 and not Ubuntu.  Yet I prefer Postfix over Exim.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have any special requirements, I would definitely go with Postfix. Apart from being a very capable MTA in general, the part about it being the default choice also means that there will be more easily available documentation.

Assuming you answer properly on the questions asked during the install (*apt-get install postfix*) you will get an ok configuration to start of. Depending on whatever you also want to listen on SMTP you should choose either *Internet with smarthost* or *Satellite system*.

Also, see https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/mail-postfix

Comment: Thanks.

I new to this so I have some more questions.

Given that this MTA will deliver mail to the SMTP/POP3 server outside AWS, do I also need to configure the following sections:

- Maildir
- SMTP Authentication
- Digital certificate
- TLS encryption
- Configuring SASL

I am assuming not.

Which port needs to be open for MTA to deliver mail to the SMTP server?

Do I need to enter the base (first) domain name I will be hosting on the EC2 instance (mail.example.com). Note, I will be hosting more than one domains?

Thanks.

Comment: One more question.

I am not using Elastic IP, could I leave the public IP out in this entry (127.0.0.0/8, 192.168.0/24)?

Thanks.

Comment: Could someone help please? Thanks.